# C++ symbol analysis: how to determine which static initialization is performed?

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, static-initialization

I want to analyze what causes the huge size of my shared C++ library which is compiled by GCC (v.6.1.1) on Linux.

`readelf -sW libfoo.so` tells me that are particularly big functions called `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0`, e.g:

```
000000000026c420 10272 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   12 __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) [clone .constprop.1774]
```

I added `-Wl,-Map,foo.map` to `CXX` flags to generate a linker map file.
Looking for `0x000000000026c420` in that map file yields:

```
.text.startup  0x000000000026c420     0x2825 CMakeFiles/foo.dir/bar.cpp.o
```

So now I know that `bar.cpp` is the translation unit which causes the static initialization, but said file does not contain any `static` variables. However, it includes lots of headers.

How do I find out exactly which variables are statically initialized in those functions?

Comment: You probably use _#include <iostream>_ which defines `static ios_base::Init __ioinit;`.

Answer (score 2):

Compile your program with:
*-g3 -Wa,-adhln*

You will get the assembly code with source code.
Inside the assembly code you will find something like:

```
_Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii:
```

And all parts of your code, which define a static variable will be mention there until the next return (`ret`).

**Example**

Source:

```
struct Foo {
    Foo() {}
};

static Foo a;
static Foo b;
```

Compile:

```
g++ text.cpp -c -O0 -g3 -Wa,-ahln > out.txt
```

Assembly:

```
35              _Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii:
36                  .LFB3:
3:text.cpp      **** };
4:text.cpp      **** 
5:text.cpp      **** static Foo a;
6:text.cpp      **** static Foo b;
37                      .loc 1 6 0
38                      .cfi_startproc
39 0000 55              pushq   %rbp
40                      .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
41                      .cfi_offset 6, -16
42 0001 4889E5          movq    %rsp, %rbp
43                      .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
44 0004 4883EC10        subq    $16, %rsp
45 0008 897DFC          movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
46 000b 8975F8          movl    %esi, -8(%rbp)
47                      .loc 1 6 0
48 000e 837DFC01        cmpl    $1, -4(%rbp)
49 0012 751D            jne .L4
50                      .loc 1 6 0 is_stmt 0 discriminator 1
51 0014 817DF8FF        cmpl    $65535, -8(%rbp)
51      FF0000
52 001b 7514            jne .L4
5:text.cpp      **** struct Foo {
    Foo() {}
};

static Foo a;
static Foo b;

53                      .loc 1 5 0 is_stmt 1 discriminator 3
54 001d BF000000        movl    $_ZL1a, %edi
54      00
55 0022 E8000000        call    _ZN3FooC1Ev
55      00
56                      .loc 1 6 0 discriminator 3
57 0027 BF000000        movl    $_ZL1b, %edi
57      00
58 002c E8000000        call    _ZN3FooC1Ev
58      00
59                  .L4:
60                      .loc 1 6 0 is_stmt 0
61 0031 90              nop
62 0032 C9              leave
63                      .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
64 0033 C3              ret
65                      .cfi_endproc
```

These two

```
54 001d BF000000        movl    $_ZL1a, %edi
57 0027 BF000000        movl    $_ZL1b, %edi
```

are your static variables.  With *c++filt* you can get the correct variable name.

The constructor:

```
call    _ZN3FooC1Ev
```